# XSD Schema Validation seems to ignore required Attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm using XmlReader to validate my XMLfiles against my XSD schema file and it is working with one exception: It is not reporting missing required Attributes.

It does, however, report Attributes that do not conform to the XSD (name spelled wrong, disallowed contents)

For example, both of these will validate without a warning, even though **both** Attributes are required:

```
<Margin Units="IN">
<Margin Units="IN" Center="true">
```

Yet these will throw a warning (where Units is an Enum and Center is a Boolean):

```
<Margin Units="IN" Center="123">
<Margin Units="abc" Center="123">
```

To make matters more confusing (for me) the same files and conditions will fail validation using Notepad++ plugin "XML Tools", and will fail using XMLSpy.

It seems only C# / .Net does not throw a warning.

Here is my validation Code:

```
public string ValidateXML(string sXmlString)
{
    validationErr = "";
    try
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.CloseInput = true;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationHandler;
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
                                   XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
                                   XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;

        StringReader r = new StringReader(sXmlString);
        XmlReader validatingReader = XmlReader.Create(r, settings);
        XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDoc.Load(validatingReader); //errors are put into the validationErr var in the ValidationHandler
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        validationErr = "XML EXCEPTION: " + exc.Message + Environment.NewLine + validationErr;
    }
    return validationErr;
}

private static void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
    {
        validationErr += "XML Parse Error Line: " +
                    e.Exception.LineNumber + " Position: " +
                    e.Exception.LinePosition + " Message: " +
                    e.Exception.Message + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Here is my XSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="SampleSchema">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Margins" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Margins">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Header" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="Footer" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="LeftSide" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="RightSide" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="Units" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="CenterHorizontal" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="CenterVertical" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="PriorityHorizontal" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="PriorityVertical" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Header">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Footer">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="LeftSide">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="RightSide">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:attribute name="Units" default="PT">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="IN"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="MM"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="PT"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="CenterHorizontal" type="xs:boolean" default="true">
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="CenterVertical" type="xs:boolean" default="true">
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="PriorityHorizontal" default="Left">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Left"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Right"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="PriorityVertical" default="Header">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Header"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Footer"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SampleSchema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sample.xsd">
    <Margins Units="PT" CenterHorizontal="false" CenterVertical="false" PriorityVertical="Header">
        <Header>36</Header>
        <Footer>36</Footer>
        <LeftSide>36</LeftSide>
        <RightSide>36</RightSide>
    </Margins>
</SampleSchema>
```

Am I going to have to write code to explicitly check for the Attributes in the XML file once the initial validation succeeds?

Or is there a way to get the XmlReader Validation to throw these warnings?

Comment: Can you attach your xsd and sample xml which should fail but does not?

Comment: @Evk - ok, I've added my xsd and xml samples

Comment: Are you really need a defaults for a required attributes? Have you tried to  remove defaults?

Comment: @ViacheslavIvanov - I can remove the defaults if they are the cause of my problem

Comment: @ViacheslavIvanov - GOT IT! Removing the defaults for the Attributes resolved the problem. Missing Attribute(s) are now reported. Thanks for pointing that out. If you make you comment an answer I'll be happy to select it.

Comment: Note that having both `use=required` and default value is actually invalid (according to xsd specification). It's interesting that even such "heavy" tool as Oxygen xml editor does not spot that because of "ref" usage (if you put both "use" and "default" on the same xs:attribute without "ref" - it will say that schema is indeed invalid.

Comment: @Evk - Yes it seems odd to me that those two cannot be combined since you can do it for elements.

Comment: Well this question suggests that you agree with specification, because otherwise you won't complain no error is produced by .NET validator - there is a default, so no problem if attribute is missing.

Comment: No - in fact it's the opposite - I do not agree with the spec. I see no reason why 'required' and a default are not allowed. And it is absolutely a problem if the Attribute is 'required' and missing!

Comment: But that is contradictory. If default and required are both allowed - there is no reason to complain about missing attribute (if attribute is missing - it means it has default value). If you complain - default is useless, because it never can be used (if you always provide value in xml - what's the point of default then?). So I'm with spec - required means attribute should always be specified in xml, in which case default makes no sense.

Comment: @Evk - no, not necessarily. Your assumption is that my CODE implements a default. When in fact, I (was) forcing the Attribute to have a default. Not the same thing.... Plus, absence of a value is not a good indicator of intent whereas explicitly setting a value (and being forced to) is. Anyway, I can state categorically what my own dis/agreement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove "default" in attribute definition. [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256143.aspx):

> …Processors of the schema should act as if the attribute was specified with the default value if it was not actually in the instance document.

Looks like this is why "required" validation does not work.